# ParkingSimulation infinite while loop crisis

Tags: java, loops, simulator

I'm a beginning computer science student and we've been asked to complete a project that animates random generated car objects moving to randomly generated parking spots on a city map grid. I've developed a GUI for the buttons, text fields, and text areas. Everything works as required except for at the end of the animation, when all cars have reached parking spots, I need to display analytics in my JTextArea. My buttons are set up properly and I will show you where the code takes place below:

```
    else if (e.getSource() == start) {

    setAnimate(true);

    if(simulator.simulationFinished()) {
        createAnalytics();
    }

    }
```

So here I have implemented an action listener on the button "start" that begins the animation. Currently it:

1. currently it begins the animation and all the cars travel to the parking spots as intended.
2. it displays analytics that are derived from before the animation began (Analytics include: car ID, number of moves, average number of spots tried, average distance travelled)
3. then the animation will conclude.
4. If I press the start button again it will display the proper analytics.

I know that in order for the program to display the right analytics the moment the program finishes I most likely need a while loop, however I haven't been able to dream anything up that will not create an infinite loop and require me to manually terminate the program via console.

```
    while(!simulator.simulationFinished()) {
    if(simulator.simulationFinished() == true)break; {
    createAnalytics();
    }
    }
```

I've also tried this among several hundred other variations of all the loops in existence. Following from my logic, I need the while loop so that it will keep checking to see if the simulation is finished so that I can execute my method that generates analytics, but if don't give the while loop something to do it just goes on forever and crashes. I'm at a loss, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First: no, you don't need a while loop necessarily. You could use the [observer pattern](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ch/2011/12/observer-design-pattern-java-example.html) instead (for example) and your object would be notified as soon as the simulation had finished. As to your question: the `if` inside the while is obviously superfluous (as is the `== true`). The real problem seems to be that `simulator.simulationFinished()` *never* returns true. Could you post the code of that function and the code (and any code that directly influences the return value of it)?

Answer (score 1):

Without going into details, there's a serious problem with your `while` loop.

See, it loops as long as `simulator.simulationFinished()` returns `false`. 
However, within the loop, you check for the opposite - which will never happen.

I would recommend using listeners of some sort, although the requirement is not clear enough for me to advise any further.